# Removing an autorun application (in Windows 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, autorun

I have installed Check Point Endpoint Security VPN on my Windows 10 (x64) machine. The software automatically loads on start up - which I do not want.

However, the software is *not* listed in the task manager under the "Startup" tab. Neither can I find the application in any of [these](https://www.akadia.com/services/windows_registry.html) registry keys.

Isn't there a better way to remove an application from autorun? This shouldn't be that hard. I even tried with 3rd party software like [this](https://www.chemtable.com/autorun-organizer.htm), but even that barely lists more than what the task manaager already does.

Comment: try this software: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns

Answer (score 0):

Check the folder or registry if it could be found.

Startup folder's location for all users is as follows:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp
```

Startup folder's location for current user is as follows:

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

Startup registry's location for all users is as follows:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
```

Startup registry's location for current user is as follows:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
```

Have you download the autoruns tool from official website?
https://docs.microsoft.com/zh-cn/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns